# What is the most effective way to move items within a vector?

Tags: c++, stl

I've seen some special cases where `std::rotate` could be used or a combination with one of the search algorithms but generally: when one has a vector of N items and wants to code function like:

```
void move( int from, int count, int to, std::vector<int>& numbers );
```

I've been thinking about creation of a new vector + `std::copy` or combination of insert/erase but I can't say I ended up with some nice and elegant solution.

Comment: It might be obvious already, but I'd still like to point out that moving big chunks of memory around is always less efficient than moving small references to memory around. For this reason, doing the operations you describe are much more efficiently implemented using e.g. a `std::list` instead of a `std::vector`.

Comment: Should the `move` function work correctly in case the source and destination regions overlap?

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: you're right, it's just this is what I have to work with. And yes, the source and destination can overlap.

Comment: UPDATE: Heh, this is awkward, I went to the guy who specified the functionality and told me they can't overlap after all. I guess that makes things a lot easier.

Comment: `rotate` **is** the best way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14580001/634821

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's always important to profile before jumping to any conclusions. The contiguity of `vector`'s data memory may offer significant caching benefits that node-based containers don't. So, perhaps you could give the direct approach a try:

```
void move_range(size_t start, size_t length, size_t dst, std::vector<T> & v)
{
  const size_t final_dst = dst > start ? dst - length : dst;

  std::vector<T> tmp(v.begin() + start, v.begin() + start + length);
  v.erase(v.begin() + start, v.begin() + start + length);
  v.insert(v.begin() + final_dst, tmp.begin(), tmp.end());
}
```

In C++11, you'd wrap the iterators in the first and third line into `std::make_move_iterator`.

(The requirement is that `dst` not lie within `[start, start + length)`, or otherwise the problem is not well-defined.)

Comment: I think your "length - start >= 0" condition isn't correct else I would be forbidden to copy 2 elements from index 10 for example.

Comment: @Miro: Of course, that was silly, let me fix. I meant `length >= 0`, but that's automatic.

Comment: Now it makes sense. I've tried to fix one small typo (two ':' in the final_dst line) but I haven't got enough privileges, so feel free to do so.

Comment: @Miro: Done, thanks! I do mistype the ternary conditional more than anything else, not sure why.

Answer (score 9):

Depending on the size of the vector and the ranges involved, this might be less expensive than performing copy/erase/insert.

```
template <typename T>
void move_range(size_t start, size_t length, size_t dst, std::vector<T> & v)
{
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator first, middle, last;
    if (start < dst)
    {
        first  = v.begin() + start;
        middle = first + length;
        last   = v.begin() + dst;
    }
    else
    {
        first  = v.begin() + dst;
        middle = v.begin() + start;
        last   = middle + length;
    }
    std::rotate(first, middle, last);
}
```

(This assumes the ranges are valid and they don't overlap.)

Comment: This works great. I wish it was in the standard library. Maybe time to write up a proposal.

Answer (score 2):

Pre-C++11 (although the following remains valid) you can get more efficient "moves" for contained types which specialise/overload `std::swap`. To take advantage of this, you would need to do something like

```
std::vector<Foo> new_vec;
Foo tmp;

for (/* each Foo&f in old_vec, first section */) {
    swap (f, tmp);
    new_vec .push_back (tmp);
}

for (/* each Foo&f in old_vec, second section */) {
    swap (f, tmp);
    new_vec .push_back (tmp);
}

for (/* each Foo&f in old_vec, third section */) {
    swap (f, tmp);
    new_vec .push_back (tmp);
}

swap (new_vec, old_vec);
```

The above may also give good results for C++11 if Foo has a move-operator but hasn't specialised `swap`.

Linked lists or [some clever sequence type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aString_data_structures) might work out better if `Foo` doesn't have move semantics or an otherwise-optimised `swap`

Note also that if the above is in a function

```
std::vector<Foo> move (std::vector<Foo> old_vec, ...)`
```

then you might be able to perform the whole operation [without copying anything, even in C++98](http://pizer.wordpress.com/2009/06/25/c-exploiting-copy-elisions/) but for this to work you will need to [pass by value](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/) and **not** by reference, which goes against the conventional prefer-pass-by-reference wisdom.

Comment: Actually it might be recommended **not** to call `std::swap` for this. It would be normal to place `swap(Foo&, Foo&)` in the same namespace as `Foo`, and by requesting `std::swap` you are not letting ADL find the right overload.

Comment: You're supposed to put your own specialisations of `swap` into the `std` namespace.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but AFAIK that is not a rule-of-thumb. You are only allowed to specialize the function, but you can't partially specialize functions. - Any piece of high-quality code (including standard library implementations) should be using ADL to find suitable **overload** for swap. - BTW, I don't see at all where your algorithm is performing any kind of rotation. It just copies everything over and then swaps everything back as it was.

Comment: @spraff: Specializations are not new declarations you can choose to put anywhere. And you are not allowed to add overloads in the std namespace. The proper way to is to do: (a) provide a swap overload in the same namespace of your class so that ADL will pick it up and (b) specialize std::swap if possible. (b) is not possible if you're dealing with a class template -- at least not in C++03. As for calling swap, you should do the following: `using std::swap; swap(x,y);` This way, ADL is used (which is good) and std::swap as a fallback. This is pretty much what boost::swap does, btw.

Comment: Technically, adding a "partial specialisation" is in fact adding a new function, I'm assuming `Foo` is a complete type.. BTW look again, the push into `new_vec` will be in whatever order the sections are reached, typically a different order. Then we swap the *whole* container, preserving the new order but storing it in `old_vec`.

Comment: The purpose of std::swap specialization is to work around code that uses fully qualified std::swap instead of letting ADL pick the right swap function.

Comment: I was surprised to learn it too, but I spoke to a standards committee member personally about it a while ago -- he insists std::swap should be fully-qualified and specialised in the std namespace.

Comment: OK, so either the first or third section is not contiguous? It is not clear when presented with a single for each loop. - As to code that uses `std::swap`: older versions of MinGW implemented `iter_swap` in terms of direct assignments. The entire algorithms header probably never called `swap` at all! :)

Comment: We should follow what the standard algorithms that use `swap` do. IIRC, C++03 either didn't properly specify this or else there were some dodgy implementations, and I haven't checked C++11. But if `std::sort` ignores ADL-overloaded `swap`, then fully-qualify `swap` when you call it. If `sort` finds either an ADL-overload or a specialization, then you should too. My inclination is the latter, and that's what gcc does in `std::iter_swap`. The former hits trouble when you write a class template: you cannot partially specialize or overload `std::swap`, so ADL is the only way.

Comment: So, personally I think that committee member was giving bad style advice, because it means that if `Foo` is typedef for some instantiation of a class template, then you will not get the author's efficient version of `swap` unless he has illegally overloaded `std::swap`. You'll fall back to the inefficient generic `std::swap`. No doubt there was some reason for the advice, but I don't know what that would be, and it would have to be worth a potentially crippling performance cost.

Comment: Another approach is to exclusively use `std::iter_swap` instead of `std::swap`, passing a pointer if you don't have an iterator. This makes the issue of whether to `use std::swap` or not go away -- nobody ADL-overloads `std::iter_swap`, so you can just fully-qualify it.

Comment: Actually, I take it all back. My memory was deceiving me. It should be plain old unqualified `swap`.

Comment: @visitor: A standard library that uses ADL to make an unqualified call to `swap` is *broken* - it won't function correctly if there's a user defined function called swap that doesn't behave like `std::swap` (and nothing in the standard specifies the behaviour of functions called swap outside of namespace `std`).

Comment: @Joe: What guarantee is there that a user-defined specialization of `std::swap` performs swapping correctly? - Anyway, at least the C++11 standard itself recommends the idiom for user code `using std::swap; swap(a, b);`! In practice, `swap` is a "special" function, and it is entirely your fault if you give it a different meaning.

Comment: @UncleBens (*swap is a "special" function, and it is entirely your fault if you give it a different meaning*): I'm not saying that providing a `swap` that doesn't behave well is a good idea - it's not. It's a horrible idea. But the standard does not allow standard library implementations to malfunction in the case that the user does something stupid but legal.

Comment: @UncleBens (*What guarantee is there that a user-defined specialization of std::swap performs swapping correctly?*): User provided specializations of functions in `namespace std` must "meet the requirements of the original template" - this language appears in all three revisions of the C++ standard (section 17.6.4.2.1 for C++11).

Comment: @Joe: C++03 is probably silent about it. In C++11 algorithms like `sort` require the type to be swappable, and the description of swappable types says that the overload set for `swap` function includes overloads found by ADL.

Comment: @UncleBens: You're quite right, as of C++11 there are requirements placed on user defined swap fuinctions.