# std: container c++ move to front

Tags: c++, list, stl, vector, swap

I'm looking for a std container like a std::list that can efficiently move an element to the front:

```
a-b-c-d-e
```

move "b" to front:

```
a-c-d-e-b
```

There is no such function in the std containers. Therefor, I think I must combine a remove and push_front function but has anyone can find a better idea?

Thank in advance.

Comment: What does "efficiently" mean?

Comment: goode question ... I mean better than removing it and creating it at the front.
If I had to implement it from scratch (in C), I could simply make a.next point to "c", c.prev point to "a", b.prev point to "e", b.next point to NULL, front point to "b" and e.next point to "b"... that would be efficient; but re-implementing a container is a little bit too time consuming ;)

Comment: The "fast" list solution is changing lots of pointers (8 bytes each in 64-bit code) at random postions in potentially uncached memory. A vector of five elements (like in the example) will possibly fit in a single cache line and be very fast.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you don't have to maintain the order of the other elements,
then the simplest solution is doubtlessly just to swap the
element you want with the first element in the container.  This
will be efficient with *all* containers.

Otherwise, `std::list` offers a `splice` operation which could
be used.  Something like the following, I think:

```
void
moveToFront( 
    std::list<MyType>& list,
    std::list<MyType>::iterator element )
{
    if ( element != list.begin() ) {
        list.splice( list.begin(), list, element, std::next( element ) );
    }
}
```

This should end up with only a couple of pointer operations, and
*no* copies.  On the other hand, `std::list` can be very slow in
general (because of its poor locality); I'd measure very
carefully against the naïve implementation using `std::vector`,
to make sure it was a win globally.  Eliminating all copies here
may not be a win if iterating to find the element you want to
move to the front is ten time more expensive.  (A lot of this
depends on how expensive `MyType` is to copy, and how large it
is.  If `sizeof(MyType)` is close to the size of a page, or
accessing `MyType` ends up accessing a lot of indirectly
allocated objects, the locality argument won't hold.)

With an `std::vector`, rather than the obvious `erase`/`insert`

```
void
moveToFront( 
    std::vector<MyType>& list,
    std::vector<MyType>::iterator element )
{
    MyType tmp( *element );
    std::copy_backwards( list.begin(), std::prev( element ), element );
    *list.begin() = tmp;
}
```

This will result in less copies than the `erase` (which copies
all of the following elements) `insert` (which also copies all
of the following elements—which means all of the elements,
because we are inserting at the beginning) pattern.

Comment: Any reason not to use `list.front() = tmp` instead of `*list.begin() = tmp`?

Answer (score 18):

On `std::vector`, you could use `std::rotate`, which has linear complexity

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> v = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };

int main()
{
   std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ",")); 
   std::cout << "\n";

   // swap ranges [1, 2) and [2, 5)
   auto it = std::next(v.begin(), 1); // O(1)
   auto rb = std::next(it);
   auto re = v.end();
   std::rotate(it, rb, re); // O(N)

   std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));   
   std::cout << "\n";
}
```

On a `std::list` you could use the member function `splice`, which (given iterators) has constant complexity

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>

std::list<int> v = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };

int main()
{
   std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ",")); 
   std::cout << "\n";

   auto it = std::next(v.begin(), 1); // O(N)
   auto rb = std::next(it);
   auto re = v.end();   
   v.splice(it, v, rb, re); // O(1)

   std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
   std::cout << "\n";   
}
```

**NOTE**: the last element is conventially denoted as `back` in the STL containers, and the first element as `front`. For `std::vector`, getting iterators to a certain element is constant time, and swapping is linear time. For `std::list`, getting iterators is linear time, but splicing into the same list is constant time. However, the much better memory caching behavior of vector is also important as **[this benchmark](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Keynote-Bjarne-Stroustrup-Cpp11-Style)** by Stroustrup shows.

**UPDATE**: Several commenters mentioned simply swapping elements: this only applies if you want to transform `a-b-c-d-e` into `a-e-c-d-b`. In that case, use `std::iter_swap` on any container you like. For the transformation of `a-b-c-d-e` into `a-c-d-e-b`, use `std::rotate` or `list::splice`.

Comment: Using `std::list` and a remove-and-push operation would have constant complexity...

Comment: Is that more efficient then a remove and insert of a single element?

Comment: @MichaelWild But with a constant factor so much higher that it would likely be slower.  (Of course, this depends on the size of the container and the type being moved.)

Comment: Removing a link from a `std::list` and inserting it somewhere else is really very cheap. I would be very surprised if the `std::vector` implementation was faster except for pathological cases.

Comment: @MichaelWild tnx, see updated answer. Note also the presentation by Stroustrup which gives surprising results for doing inserts on a `std::vector`.

Comment: @MichaelWild Prepare to be surprised.  Erasing an element from a `std::list`, then inserting it at the head, involves two copies of the element, _plus_ a free and an allocation.  Freeing and allocating memory can easily cost more time than it takes to copy a couple of hundred `int` or `double`.  For a collection of less than a thousand `int`, `std::vector` will probably beat `std::list` for this operation.  Even a solution involving spicing will likely touch several different pages, where as for smaller data sets, the solution with `vector` may never leave have a cache miss.

Comment: @rhalbersma The `rotate` solution changes the order of the remaining elements.  If this is acceptable, just swapping with the first element is far more efficient.

Comment: @JamesKanze No that's not correct: `std::rotate` rotates the entire subranges. see http://liveworkspace.org/code/QItmN$17 The 0,1,2,3,4 sequence is rotated into 0,2,3,4,1. This is exactly the type of transformation the OP requested. See update to answer.