# Is there a way to extract a node from std::list similar to what std::map::extract does?

Tags: c++, stl, c++17, stdmap, stdlist

For my task, I'm using `std::list<Key>` to maintain the order of elements in a makeshift LRU cache. So, one of the frequent operations is taking a list element out and putting it back on the list's front.

Obviously, it can be implemented by first using `std::list::erase` and then `std::list::push_front`. However, I don't like the idea of dealing with memory reallocation when all I wanna do is move a list node to a different position.

This is exactly what the `extract` method allows us to do for `std::map`, `std::set` etc: taking a node out, modifying it and putting it back with no reallocation at all.

Is there a reasonable explanation why `std::list` lacks the same functionality, and is there a workaround to mimic it with existing class API?

Comment: I don't see a reason why wouldn't extend this idea even more, and have _intrusive containers_ , like boost intrusive list and boost intrusive map in STL, and make non-intrusive built on top of intrusive.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14580812/580083) is relevant. You can do this with a single command `list.splice(list.begin(), list, iter)`, where `iter` points to an element you want to move to the beginning.

Comment: You can also check the generated assembly, which basically just reassigns relevant pointers: https://godbolt.org/z/eNAxpC.

Comment: @DanielLangr That's interesting. In my quick research it seemed that splice was "from one list to another". It does make sense that it would work in the same list though.

Comment: @DanielLangr, the eel.is link you provided below shows that one of the `splice` overloads does indeed forbid splicing from list to itself, the one that takes the whole source list contents. So you are only in part incorrect.

Comment: @Semisonic Wasn't your second comment addressed to Blastfurnance instead of to me? I didn't provide any eel.is link neither I told anything about same/different lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [`std::list::splice`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice) member function that might be what you want. It operates on the internal pointers of the list nodes. <strike>I don't see a way to splice from/to the same list but</strike> you could splice to a temporary (empty) `std::list` and then splice back to the front of the original list.

On review, splicing is allowed within the same list. It is undefined to splice an entire list to itself. Splicing a single element into the same list is okay and splicing a range of elements is okay as long as the destination position isn't included in the spliced-from range. (Thank you, Daniel Langr)

Comment: `splice` will do, thank you! It does feel hacky though. Still don't understand what made the developers of the Standard skip on giving `extract` to `std::list`

Comment: I don't know. That's probably one of those "submit a proposal if you want it" things.

Comment: Do note that this function has a linear complexity.

Comment: @Ayxan I think it's [constant time](http://eel.is/c++draft/list.ops#10) for splicing a single node.

Comment: Interesting. I must have mixed it with some other function. Thank you for the reference

Comment: @Blastfurnace Obtain the iterator takes linear time unless you already have it.

Comment: @LIUQingyuan, storing the iterators in an `std::unordered_map` object along with the cache values is something I was gonna do anyways. So, in terms of complexity, this solution is as optimal as it could be even if `std::list` had the `extract` method.

Comment: @Semisonic I guess the purpose for adding `extract` was to allow altering (constant) keys of elements in `set` or `map`. With `list`, there is no such need. But I understand your motivation.