# Moving an item in a vector

Tags: c++

What is the most efficient way to move an item in a vector from lets say 4th position to 2nd position.The vector in this case can contain more than 100 elements.The algorithm for moving elements should be based on iterators or the indexes (meaning find the 4 the element(source) and 2nd element(destination) ),which one is better.I already tried based on indexes ([What is the most effective way to move items within a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527674/what-is-the-most-effective-way-to-move-items-within-a-vector),but) in my case getting the iterator for 4th and 2nd position is easier than to calculate the indexes.

Comment: Perhaps a vector is not the appropriate data structure in this case. A linked list.

Comment: if it is a vector of primitives/PODs, you can copy the moved element to a temp, use `memmove`, then copy the element to its destination.

Comment: `std::swap(vec[2], vec[4]);` . You didn't say what you wanted to happen with the one already in 2nd position; this solution swaps it into 4th position.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: shouldn't that be `vec[1]` and `vec[3]`? ;-).  Anyway, the question doesn't even make it clear that `vec[1] = vec[3]` isn't the kind of "move an item" wanted, assuming elements support move semantics, but I think SchighSchagh's interpretation of requirements is very likely right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you can use `std::rotate` to this end.

```
vector<T> vec = ...
vector<T>::iterator from = ...
vector<T>::iterator to = ...
if(from < to ) {
    rotate(from, from+1, to+1);
} else if (from > to) {
    rotate(to, from, from+1);
}
```

Disclaimer: untested code

By the way, you can get the vector index from iterator easily with eg,

```
vector<T> vec = ...
vector<T>::iterator it = ...
size_t idx = it - vec.begin();
```

Comment: Great lead, though to rotate right you need to use `reverse_iterator`s... see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) for details + example.

Comment: @TonyD Not a bad idea, but I think my way will work also since rotate right by 1 is same as rotate left by (N-1) where N is the (absolute) distance between `from` and `to`. Also, it sounds like OP has regular (forward) iterators already.

Comment: @SchighSchagh one should prefer the use `std::distance` instead of subtracting iterators, as the former works with all types of iterators and not just random-access ones. The `std::distance` uses tag dispatching internally, so has O(1) complexity for random-access iterators.

Comment: @SchighSchagh: oh yeah - seems it all works out the same... nice one!

Comment: @vsoftco good point, but since OP specified `vector`, then `std::distance` uses `operator-` anyway, so it's the same in this case.