# Best way to move item in vector

Tags: c++, vector

I am looking for a fast way to move an item inside a vector array one position + or -. I hope someone can help me. I use C++.

Comment: What happens to the item that was already in the destination position?

Comment: The question is almost impossible to answer in its current form. You will need to be a lot more specific. In its current form, the best you can hope for is an answer like: _given a pair of iterators `x` and `y` to the items (neither of them pointing to the `end` of the container), swap the items using `std::iter_swap(x, y)`._

Comment: Trust me: someone giving you the answer won't help you as a programmer. I suggest doing some research, writing some code, and coming back if you have a specific problem.

Comment: Have you read about std::swap yet?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527674/what-is-the-most-effective-way-to-move-items-within-a-vector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to swap neighbour elements e.g:
turn this:

```
0 1 2 3 4
```

into this:

```
1 0 2 3 4
```

you can do:

```
std::swap(v.at(i), v.at(i+1));
```

or in my example:

```
std::swap(v.at(0), v.at(1));
```

P.S. Why are you specifically asking for a fast way? Are you trying to make a [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) fast enough to pass performance tests for a [more efficient sorting alghorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Efficient_sorts)? If so, I have bad news for you: it's impossible. You'll have to implement one of more efficient algorithms or use [std::sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) from the `<algorithm>` library.

Comment: It is amazing that people always diss other peoples question without reading them well. However, 2 people answered with swap function so the question was not as bad as some people rated or commented. Some people are here just for rate people bad.

Comment: @pixbye, you kinda didn't provide enough information to make it clear what you are asking for. People had to guess what you want and people hate guessing. Ideally the first half of my answer (about turning `0 1 2 3 4` into `1 0 2 3 4`) should have been included in your question.

Comment: Sorry, I think other. To ask to movie an item inside a vector I think I do not need to pant pictures like in a children book. We all can read and think. And you have answered right way. So you understood. 
It becomes more and more a flaw to ask online people things because you always get a shitstorm or a bad rating. It is not possible to communicate on a correct way.Think about it. The question was really simple.